# How to write Azure blob metadata within Azure ML pipeline component

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

The blob container is available as an AML blob datastore within the pipeline component
Here is the relevant YAML for the component

```
outputs:
  datapath:
    type: uri_folder
    path: <datastore>
```

I can create a new blob using

```
with open(os.path.join(args.datapath, "content.txt"),"w") as f:
        f.write(content)
```

How to update the metadata of this blob after creating it? I am using AML v2, python SDK.